Can't understand why the model is unsat
I'm working for a university problem dealing with constraint programing and one of the task is about using Z3py and SAT to solve a problem.
The problem consist in m courier n object and the objective is to minimize the maximum distance travelled by each courier.
The other data are:

l the array of the maximum load for every courier,
s the array of the weight of every item,
D the array for the distance of every point from each other, e.g. D[i][j] is the distance from item i to item j.

The principal constraints are:

every item must be delivered.
every courier must respect their maximum load
every courier must start and end in the origin, the distance for the origin point are in the D matrix in the n row and column, e.g D[n][i] means the distance from the origin to item i

This is the formulation that I thought of, the idea was to use two matrix of boolean variables:

p: a value p[j][k] is true if the item j is in position k
b: a value b[i][j] is true if the courier i deliver the item j.

from z3 import *

def symMax(l):
  m = l[0]
  for v in l[1:]:
    m = If(v > m, v, m)
  return m

def precedes(a1, a2):
    if not a1:
        return True
    if not a2:
        return False
    return Or(And(a1[0] == True, a2[0] == False), And(a1[0] == a2[0], precedes(a1[1:], a2[1:])))

def multiple_couriers_problem_sat(m, n, l, s, D):
    # definition of a 3d array for the path of each courier
    p = [[Bool(f"p_{j}_{k}") for k in range(n//m+2)] for j in range(n)]
    # definition of a matrix that binds a courier with its items
    b = [[Bool(f"b_{i}_{j}") for j in range(n)] for i in range(m)]

    # solver instance
    solver = Optimize()
    solver.set("timeout", 300000)

    # channeling constraint between b and p
    for i in range(m):
      for j in range(n):
        solver.add(Implies(b[i][j], And(exactly_one(p[j]))))
    # channeling constraint between p and b
    for j in range(n):
      solver.add(Implies(And(exactly_one(p[j])), And(exactly_one([b[i][j] for i in range(m)]))))

    for j in range(n):
      solver.add(exactly_one([b[i][j] for i in range(m)]))

# each courier load capacity is respeceted
    for i in range(m):
      solver.add(Sum([s[j] * b[i][j] for j in range(n)]) <= l[i])

    # each courier has to distribute at least one item
    for i in range(m):
      solver.add(at_least_one(b[i]))

    # ensures that the items that the courier delivers are in the first positions of the path
    for i in range(m):
     for k in range(n//m+1):
       solver.add(Implies(Sum([And(p[j][k], b[i][j])  for j in range(n)]) == 0, Sum([And(p[j][k+1], b[i][j])  for j in range(n)]) == 0))


    solver.add(PbEq([(x,1) for x in [p[j][0] for j in range(n)]], m)) 

    #
    for i1 in range(m):
      for i2 in range(i1+1, m):
        if ((i1 != i2) and (l[i1] == l[i2])):
          solver.add(precedes(b[i1], b[i2]))

    # computing the distance
    d = [0 for i in range(m)]
    for i in range(m):
        total_distance = 0
        for k in range(n//m+1):
            for j1 in range(n):
                for j2 in range(n):
                    if j1 != j2:
                        total_distance += If(And(And(b[i][j1], p[j1][k]), And(b[i][j2], p[j2][k+1])), D[j1][j2], 0)
                total_distance += If(And(And(b[i][j1], p[j1][k]), Sum([b[i][t] * p[t][k+1] for t in range(n)]) == 0), D[j1][n] , 0)

        # Add the distance from the origin to the first point
        first_path = Sum([If(And(b[i][j], p[j][0]), D[n][j], 0) for j in range(n)])
        total_distance += first_path
        d[i] = total_distance

    # ascendent order of the courier travelled distances
    for i in range(m-1):
      solver.add(d[i] >= d[i+1])

    max_d = Int('max_d')
    max_d = symMax(d)

    solver.minimize(max_d)

    if solver.check() != unsat:
      return solver.model()
    else:
      return 'unsat'

This formulation work for some istance but give unsat for this one:
2
3
18 30
20 17 6
0 21 86 99 
21 0 71 80 
92 71 0 61 
59 80 61 0 

I really can't understand why it doesn't work.
To help undestand the problem here is an example of solution for this istance:
2
6
15 10
3 2 6 5 4 4
0 3 4 5 6 6 2 
3 0 1 4 5 7 3 
4 1 0 5 6 6 4 
4 4 5 0 3 3 2 
6 7 8 3 0 2 4 
6 7 8 3 2 0 4 
2 3 4 3 4 4 0 

The solution to this istance is:
[['p_3_0', 'p_2_1', 'p_0_2'], ['p_1_0', 'p_4_1', 'p_5_2']]
14

In this solution the array contain an array for every courier and each one of this array is the path of the corresponding courier.
So in this solution the first courier travel first to the item 3, then to item 2 , then to the item 0, in the solution is implied that the item in position 0 is preceded by the origin and the last item is followed by the origin.

I'm still trying to make sense of the problem: Don't you need knowledge of where each object is, and what its final destination must be?

In the matrix D you have every distance for every point and the distance of every object are these point, for example a valid paths would be, (n is the origin) n-3 3-5 5-6 6-n, which means that the courier starts in the origin, deliver the object 3,5,6 and then comeback to the origin. Imagine it like all the item are in the origin and courier must deliver them and go back to the origin

I'm finding this still very confusing, and looks like there might be a language barrier as well. It might help the readers of this forum to add a worked-out example, directly editing your question.

added an example for clarification
